# Insertion in object instantiation while looping in objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a class "Customer" that I want to instantiate a specific number of its objects based on an array count.
In other words I want to do the following but in Objective-C

> java:

```
for (int i = 1; I <= array.lenght; i++) { 
    Customer customer[i] = new Customer;
}
```

so if [array count] == 3 I will get:

> customer1
>   customer2
>   customer3

How to get the variable i to be a part of the definition?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to refer to these customers by number, just keep them in an array (NSArray).

```
NSMutableArray* customers = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) [customers addObject:[Customer new]];
```

Now, given just a number, you can instantly find that customer by index into the array.

```
Customer* aCustomer = customers[1]; // or whatever
```

If you really want to be able to refer to them by a name of the form "customer1", keep them in a dictionary (NSDictionary) and use that name as a key (although a name with a number in it like that has a "bad smell" — the array solution is better).